# Register Assemble Handlebars Helpers

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

I am trying to do something that seems relatively simple from the [Assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) docs and other repos I've looked at but for some reason I'm having a problem registering my Handlebars helpers.  The helper is in helpers > helper-classgrid.js

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options, params)  { 
  Handlebars.register('classgrid', function (index, options)  { 
    gridclass: function (index, options) {
    if (index === 0 || index % 4 === 0) {
        return options.fn(this);
      }
    return options.inverse(this);
  };
};
```

My gruntfile where config.helpers = helpers:

```
assemble: {
      options: {
        layoutdir: '<%= config.guts %>/templates/layouts/',
        assetsDir: '<%= grunt.config.get("assets_dir") %>',
        environmentIsProduction: '<%= grunt.config.get("environmentIsProduction") %>',
        environmentIsDev: '<%= grunt.config.get("environmentIsDev") %>',
        data: ['<%= config.content %>/**/*.json', '<%= grunt.config.get("environmentData") %>'],
        helpers: ['<%= config.helpers %>/helper-*.js']
      },
}
```

Template code:

```
{{#classgrid @index}}
// do something here
{{/classgrid}}
```

Now when I implement my helper in my Handlerbars template and run the grunt task containing the assemble task I get the error

```
Warning: Missing helper: 'classgrid' Use --force to continue.
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong or if I have to create a separate NPM package for my helpers which it seems to suggest in the assemble docs. I've looked at these 2 repos which seem to be doing what I'm trying to do

https://github.com/buildingblocks/bb-prototype-website/blob/master/Gruntfile.js
https://github.com/ghost-town/layouts-example/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this was just a copy/paste issue, but the code above doesn't look correct... here's what should work:

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, opts, params)  { 
  Handlebars.registerHelper('classgrid', function (index, options)  { 
    if (index === 0 || index % 4 === 0) {
      return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
  });
};
```

I'll try to create a test project to make sure this is working.

Edit: After creating a test project, I see that you were using `Handlebars.register` instead of `Handlebars.registerHelper`. I've updated the code to a working solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I'll give that a try.  I think the confusion came from your docs if you look at the Params object example http://assemble.io/docs/Custom-Helpers.html

Comment: Oh, it looks like the example in the docs needs to be updated. We'll be getting to all of those soon. Let me know if what's above works for you.

Comment: Hey all works once I fixed what you suggested and cleared all my idiotic typos