# Register assemble handlebars-helpers with Express handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, assemble

I had a look at this post but it does not come up with a solution: [Register Assemble Handlebars Helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418604/register-assemble-io-handlebars-helpers)

I want to register all the helpers in https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers to my Express 4 application running express-handlebars.

So far I've tried this but the helpers are not getting registered:

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'default',
    layoutsDir: './lib/templates/layouts',
    partialsDir: './lib/templates/partials'
    helpers: require('handlebars-helpers') // Not registering correctly
});
```

How does this library work? I'm probably doing it wrong.
Are you supposed to register one at a time or can you load the all helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
    , hbsHelpers = require('handlebars-helpers');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    //code...
});
hbsHelpers.register(hbs.handlebars, {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Macgyver Martins. This worked perfectly. Weird that this would not be stated in the documentation as so many are using express-handlebars.

Comment: the [dev branch](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/tree/dev) is 143 commits ahead of master. I recommend taking a look at that branch. we'll be merging to master in the next few days

Answer (score 3):

This working for me:

In app.js:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'default',
    layoutsDir: './lib/templates/layouts',
    partialsDir: './lib/templates/partials'
    helpers: require('handlebars-helpers').helpers
});

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
```

In handlebars-helpers.js:

```
var register = function (Handlebars) {
    var helpers = {
        formatCurrency: function (currency) {
            return currency.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        },
        format_date: function (date, format) {
            return moment(date).format(format);
        },
        ...
    };

    if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
        for (var prop in helpers) {
            Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
        }
    } else {
        return helpers;
    }

};

module.exports.register = register;
module.exports.helpers = register(null);
```

In views:

```
{{formatCurrency settings.phoneNumber}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add a few ideas since this question is already 3 years. I'm using Express 4 as well with `express-handlebars` (Also nodejs 8.11 LTS). In the app.js (created by express generator).

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const hbsHelpers = require('handlebars-helpers')();
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: hbsHelpers,
});
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Tried both above answers but couldn't get them working. But noticed that in the Usage section of `handlebars-helpers` [documentation](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#usage) It says: The main export returns a function that needs to be called to expose the object of helpers.

The `express-handlebars` create function also support the `helpers` parameter as an object, such as:

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: {
        tsnumber: () => { return Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); },
    },
});
```

As you can see in this example, I defined one helper called `tsnumber` (returns Unix style timestamp), and what `helpers` get is just an object.

To further extend this functionality by combining the helper I defined (tsnumber) and the `express-handlebars`, we can use `Object.assign`.

The new structure will be:

```
config/hbsHelper.js
node_modules/
app.js
```

The config directory is a folder I created to combine two libraries.
The content of `config/hbsHelper.js` is:

```
const hbsDefaultHelpers = require('handlebars-helpers')();
const extra = {
    tsnumber: () => { return Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); },
};

const merged = Object.assign(extra, hbsDefaultHelpers);
module.exports = merged;
```

Then in the `app.js`

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const hbsHelpers = require('./config/hbsHelpers');
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: hbsHelpers,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for hbs:

```js
const hbs = require('hbs');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

hbs.registerHelper(require('handlebars-helpers')()); // register extra helpers
```